# Django ImageField specific directory is full (maximum number of files in linux dir)

Tags: python, django, linux

While having this:

```
profile_pic: ImageField = models.ImageField(
        _("profile_picture"), upload_to='profile_pic',
        blank=True, null=True)
```

And 23M record I found out that profile_pic is "full" ("no space left on device") while having 300GB free.

I thought of **splitting the the files to folders with the first 3 letters**, but how can I achieve that in the django ?

[image]

REF:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419651/mv-fails-with-no-space-left-on-device-when-the-destination-has-31-gb-of-space

https://pylessons.com/django-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is number of files in the same directoy. You can change the upload_to option like this and there will be only one file for each folder.

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

Comment: I guess number of folders will have the  same issue as number of files issue. maybe split it with first 3 letters. what should I do with current files ? should I create a screat to move them from current place ?

Comment: There is a limit of 31998 sub-directories per one directory, stemming from its limit of 32000 links per inode.1 Jun 2009

Comment: You can create a subfolder system with timestamps. Like: YYYY>MM>D>username>picture

Comment: But all current images will need to be reordered ?

Comment: I think he has to reorder them anyway. He can use user's created_on date attribute for the process.

Comment: so reording the files on linux and changing the location on django is sufficient ?

Comment: He need to update existing image records locations to new version. And thats all i think. All of them can be done via manage.py shell. I know i didn't provide the codes for this but provided info is not enough either. And there is another option using 3rd party cloud storage solutions for media files like aws buckets.